# JQuery / Javascript - Ordenar Array() multidimensional

Tags: javascript, jquery, array

Tengo el siguiente Array():

```
{
    "1 ":
        {
            "id":"12",
            "usuarioA":"1",
            "usuarioB":"2",
            "mensaje":"Hola mi amor",
            "date":"2017-01-19 03:02:12",
            "TokenID":"1",
            "remitente":"Andrey Homez",
            "destinatario":"Paola Gonzales",
            "CVX":"Paola Gonzales"
        },
    "2 ":
        {
            "id":"13",
            "usuarioA":"1",
            "usuarioB":"3",
            "mensaje":"hey chaval",
            "date":"2017-01-19 03:11:11",
            "TokenID":"2",
            "remitente":"Andrey Homez",
            "destinatario":"Felipe Gomez",
            "CVX":"Felipe Gomez"
        },
    "13 ":
        {
            "id":"11",
            "usuarioA":"1",
            "usuarioB":"1",
            "mensaje":"Hablando conmigo mismo alv :&quot;v",
            "date":"2017-01-19 02:52:13",
            "TokenID":"13",
            "remitente":"Andrey Homez",
            "destinatario":"Andrey Homez",
            "CVX":"Andrey Homez"
        }
}
```

Cómo puedo hacer que quede **ordenada** por el índice **"date"** en forma **descendente**? Es decir que quede así:

```
{
    "2 ":
        {
            "id":"13",
            "usuarioA":"1",
            "usuarioB":"3",
            "mensaje":"hey chaval",
            "date":"2017-01-19 03:11:11",
            "TokenID":"2",
            "remitente":"Andrey Homez",
            "destinatario":"Felipe Gomez",
            "CVX":"Felipe Gomez"
        },
    "1 ":
        {
            "id":"12",
            "usuarioA":"1",
            "usuarioB":"2",
            "mensaje":"Hola mi amor",
            "date":"2017-01-19 03:02:12",
            "TokenID":"1",
            "remitente":"Andrey Homez",
            "destinatario":"Paola Gonzales",
            "CVX":"Paola Gonzales"
        },

    "13 ":
        {
            "id":"11",
            "usuarioA":"1",
            "usuarioB":"1",
            "mensaje":"Hablando conmigo mismo alv :&quot;v",
            "date":"2017-01-19 02:52:13",
            "TokenID":"13",
            "remitente":"Andrey Homez",
            "destinatario":"Andrey Homez",
            "CVX":"Andrey Homez"
        }
}
```

Algo **importante** es que los números `1`,`2`,`13` deben conservarse (No me refiero a su orden).

Gracias, de antemano :)

Comment: Ese objeto que has puesto no es un array. ¿Quieres ordenar un array o los sub-objetos de un objeto?

Comment: Parece un objeto JSON

Comment: @lois6b en código es un objeto JavaScript (que en código puede ser definido en formato JSON) y como tal no es posible ordenarlo. A ver si el autor nos aclara si realmente está trabajando con arrays.

Comment: El array es la respuesta de AJAX - PHP, devuelto con `json_encode();`, es claro que es JSON.

Comment: Un pequeño editado...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema, para empezar, es que tus datos no corresponden a una matriz, si no a un objeto. JavaScript no entiende de matrices asociativas, en su lugar usa objetos y propiedades para conseguir una funcionalidad similar.

Eso significa que métodos como `sort()` no están disponibles para realizar la ordenación de los datos y, lo que es peor, **JavaScript no garantiza el orden de las propiedades a lo largo de la vida del objeto**, por lo que el resultado debería ser en todo caso una matriz, no un nuevo objeto.

Para corregir ese problema te recomiendo que tus datos los generes como matriz (usando delimitadores raíz `[]` en vez de `{}`). No tendrás pérdida alguna porque el índice de los valores es, en realidad, el campo `tokenID`.

Una vez hecha esa modificación es muy sencillo usar una función de comparación para ordenar como deseas tus datos.

Si no puedes hacer ese cambio en tu código, entonces puedes hacer una conversión objeto <-> matriz como te propuso @PaperBirdMaster , pero siempre **es mejor hacer este trabajo en origen que en el navegador del cliente**.

Este es el ejemplo de hacerlo todo como objeto (verás que el resultado se "reordena"):

```js
var datos = {
  "1":{
    "id":"12",
    "usuarioA":"1",
    "usuarioB":"2",
    "mensaje":"Hola mi amor",
    "date":"2017-01-19 03:02:12",
    "TokenID":"1",
    "remitente":"Andrey Homez",
    "destinatario":"Paola Gonzales",
    "CVX":"Paola Gonzales"
  },
  "2":{
    "id":"13",
    "usuarioA":"1",
    "usuarioB":"3",
    "mensaje":"hey chaval",
    "date":"2017-01-19 03:11:11",
    "TokenID":"2",
    "remitente":"Andrey Homez",
    "destinatario":"Felipe Gomez",
    "CVX":"Felipe Gomez"
  },
  "13":{
    "id":"11",
    "usuarioA":"1",
    "usuarioB":"1",
    "mensaje":"Hablando conmigo mismo alv :&quot;v",
    "date":"2017-01-19 02:52:13",
    "TokenID":"13",
    "remitente":"Andrey Homez",
    "destinatario":"Andrey Homez",
    "CVX":"Andrey Homez"
  }
};
var temp = [];
for (var i in datos) {
  array.push(datos[i]);
}
function sort(a,b){
  a = a.date;
  b = b.date;
  if(a < b) {
    return 1;
  } else if (a > b) {
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
}
temp.sort(sort);
salida = {};
for (var i in temp) {
  salida[temp[i].TokenID] = temp[i];
}
console.log(salida);
```

Y éste como matriz (declarando de inicio como matriz los datos, para evitar el bucle de conversión):

```js
var datos = [
  {
    "id":"12",
    "usuarioA":"1",
    "usuarioB":"2",
    "mensaje":"Hola mi amor",
    "date":"2017-01-19 03:02:12",
    "TokenID":"1",
    "remitente":"Andrey Homez",
    "destinatario":"Paola Gonzales",
    "CVX":"Paola Gonzales"
  },
  {
    "id":"13",
    "usuarioA":"1",
    "usuarioB":"3",
    "mensaje":"hey chaval",
    "date":"2017-01-19 03:11:11",
    "TokenID":"2",
    "remitente":"Andrey Homez",
    "destinatario":"Felipe Gomez",
    "CVX":"Felipe Gomez"
  },
  {
    "id":"11",
    "usuarioA":"1",
    "usuarioB":"1",
    "mensaje":"Hablando conmigo mismo alv :&quot;v",
    "date":"2017-01-19 02:52:13",
    "TokenID":"13",
    "remitente":"Andrey Homez",
    "destinatario":"Andrey Homez",
    "CVX":"Andrey Homez"
  }
];
function sort(a,b){
  a = a.date;
  b = b.date;
  if(a < b) {
    return 1;
  } else if (a > b) {
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
}
datos.sort(sort);
console.log(datos);
```

En este caso la comparación entre fechas es sencilla gracias a que parecen obtenidas de una base de datos en formato `yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS` que permite la equivalencia con la comparación directa de cadenas de caracteres.

Debes cerciorarte que esas fechas estén en UTC para evitar problemas con las comparaciones durante los periodos de un cambio de hora (paso de horario de verano a invierno y viceversa).

Comment: ¿No estás ordenando las fechas alfabéticamente? Alfabéticamente `"01-02-2017 00:00:00"` es menor que `"02-01-2017 00:00:00"`.

Comment: Esa notación de fecha no es correcta. La notación "informática" va de magnitud superior a inferior con relleno de ceros en decenas. Las notaciones más ampliamente usadas son la ISO 8601 e ISO 9075. Ambas soportan (para una misma franja horaria) comparación de texto como comparación de magnitud. Lo ideal es trabajar con UTC para evitar problemas de solapamiento de tiempo en franjas de cambio de hora.

Comment: A mí también me pasa con frecuencia, culpa de la lectura rápida ;)

Comment: Para mí funcionó más ésta respuesta, aunque el código no es tan reutilizable.

Comment: @MáximaAlekz , ¿qué parte no es reutilizable? ¿cómo podría mejorar el ejemplo?

Comment: La function Sort que tienes, sólo trabaja si hay un indice llamado "Date". De lo contrario la funcion falla.

Comment: La pregunta reza: "¿Cómo puedo hacer que quede ordenada por el índice `date` en forma descendente?". Si quieres ordenar basado en otro atributo se puede cambiar fácilmente. ¿Qué mejora desearías? Si la planteas podré hacerla. ¿Quieres que compruebe si existe o no por si hay registros que no lo tienen?

Comment: Yo sólo estoy diciendo que el código no puede ser reutilizable fácilmente para diferentes indices.

Comment: Pero sigo sin entender el problema o la pregunta que estás haciendo o la mejora que propones que haga porque modificarlo para que funcione para que ordene por otro atributo es trivial. ¿Quieres que se pueda pasar parámetro el índice por el que deseas ordenar?

Answer (score 4):

#### Problema.

> Tengo el siguiente Array():

No, eso no es un Array: es un objeto. Los objetos no ordenan sus elementos.

Según la definición de objeto de la [3ª edición de ECMAScript](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf) (traducción y resaltado míos):

> #### 4.3.3 Objeto
>
> Un objeto es un miembro del tipo `Object`. **Es una colección no ordenada de propiedades** cada una de las cuales contiene un valor primitivo, objeto o función. Una función guardada en una propiedad de un objeto es conocida como método.

#### Propuesta.

Pasa los elementos a un array, puedes hacerlo así:

```
var x = { ... todos tus datos ... };
var array = [];
for (var id in x)
{
    var obj = {};
    obj[id] = x[id];
    array.push(obj);
}
```

Los array de JavaScript disponen de una función [`sort`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp) la cuál puede recibir (opcionalmente) un parámetro que es la función de comparación. Así que crearemos una función que nos ordene de manera inversa según la propiedad `"date"` del objeto:

```
function date_descendente(a, b) {
    var split_a = a[Object.keys(a)[0]]["date"].match(/(\d+)/g);
    var split_b = b[Object.keys(b)[0]]["date"].match(/(\d+)/g);
    var date_a = new Date(split_a[0], split_a[1], split_a[2], split_a[3], split_a[4], split_a[5]);
    var date_b = new Date(split_b[0], split_b[1], split_b[2], split_b[3], split_b[4], split_b[5]);

    return date_b.getTime() - date_a.getTime();
}
```

Por lo que he podido comprobar, el objeto [`Date`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) no es construible con el formato de fecha que almacenas (si no incluyera los segundos sí sería construible). Así que separo la fecha en cada uno de los componentes y construyo la fecha a partir de ellos con el constructor que recibe año, mes, día, hora, minuto y segundo.

Para ordenar a la inversa simplemente devuelvo la resta entre el elemento de la derecha y el de la izquierda, como la función de ordenación necesita devolver un valor numérico restamos el resultado de llamar al [método `getTime`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp) de cada `Date`, que nos devuelve los milisegundos transcurridos desde el primero de Enero de 1970 a las 0 horas (que es lo que se conoce como [Tiempo UNIX](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiempo_Unix)).

Así que el código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
var array = [];
for (var id in x)
{
    var obj = {};
    obj[id] = x[id];
    array.push(obj);
}
array.sort(date_descendente);
```

Y tendrías en `array[0]` el objeto `"2"`, en el 1 `"12"` y en el 2 `"13"`.

Comment: No estoy seguro de que un objeto sea un **muembro** de Object.