# Ordenar las llaves de un objeto manualmente

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente array de objeto en mi código de JavaScript.

```
var data = [
   {
     ACC_OBSERVACIONES: 'Ninguna',
     COLOR: 'Rojo',
     MARCA: 'BMW',
     MODELO: 'i8',
     NOMBRE: 'Hoose'},
   {
     ACC_OBSERVACIONES: 'Ninguna',
     COLOR: 'Verde',
     MARCA: 'Merdedes Benz',
     MODELO: '32432',
     NOMBRE: 'Pedro'
   }
];
```

Me gustaría poder cambiar el orden de las llaves en mi objeto. ¿Es posible hacer esto?

```
var data = [
    {
      MARCA: 'BMW',
      MODELO: 'i8',
      COLOR: 'Rojo',
      ACC_OBSERVACIONES: 'Ninguna',
      NOMBRE: 'Hoose'},
    {
      MARCA: 'Merdedes Benz',
      MODELO: '32432',
      COLOR: 'Verde',
      ACC_OBSERVACIONES: 'Ninguna',
      NOMBRE: 'Pedro'
    }
 ];
```

Me he dado cuenta que se ordena alfabéticamente las llaves en automático, ¿Puedo cambiar el orden de las llaves a mi manera? Mi problema es que necesito cambiar el orden de las llaves por que utilizo un plugin que carga los datos de la variable, pero los carga en el orden que vienen y no me sirve ese orden.

Comment: ¿Qué plugin usas? ¿Cuando lo agrega al DOM no puede definirse dónde se coloca? ¿Utiliza alguna plantilla para la presentación?

Comment: Utilizo este http://holt59.github.io/datatable/ El detalle es hago una petición AJAX y el back (PHP) me retorna el JSON como viene.

Comment: La solución que veo es generar el DOM con php o javascript y luego aplicar el plugin.

Comment: @Hoose [Sorting a JSON object in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4222690/4092887)

Comment: Lo que pides no tiene sentido. Un objeto es una colección de keys sin orden alguno, si lo que quieres es un orden necesitas un array, pero con esto perderías los nombres de los keys. ¿Para que necesitas hacer esto? Estoy 100% seguro que lo que intentas hacer no es la solución a tu problema

Comment: Esta pregunta es un posible duplicado de estas otras: [Como ordenar un objeto de acuerdo a su key?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/107968/250), [Reversar el orden de iteración de las propiedades de un objeto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/88423/250), o [JQuery / Javascript - Ordenar Array() multidimensional](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/44844/250). La idea al final es la misma, que es lo que te dice Carlos en su comentario: los keys no tienen ningún orden particular dentro de un objeto. Aunque quizás alguna de las respuestas del primer enlace te puedan servir para simular lo que quieres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es obtener el DOM generado con `PHP` de la tabla completa y luego aplicar el plugin para generar la tabla filtrable.

En tu función ajax, obtener el código HTML generado por PHP y luego, seleccionarla usando:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#datatable table').datatable({
    pageSize: 5,
    sort: [true, true, false],
    filters: [true, false, 'select'],
    filterText: 'Type to filter... ',
    pagingDivSelector: "#paging-first-datatable"
});
});
```

```html
<!-- CSS files (include only one of the two files!) -->
<!-- If you are not using bootstrap: -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://holt59.github.io/datatable/css/datatable.min.css" media="screen">
<!-- If you are using bootstrap: -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://holt59.github.io/datatable/css/datatable-bootstrap.min.css" media="screen">
                    
<!-- JS files -->       
<!-- Add the following if you want to use the jQuery wrapper (you still need datatable.min.js): -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://holt59.github.io/datatable/js/datatable.jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://holt59.github.io/datatable/js/datatable.min.js"></script>

<table id="datatable">
  <thead>
     <tr>
        <th>Marca</th>
        <th>Modelo</th>
        <th>Color</th>
        <th>ACC_Observaciones</th>
        <th>Nombre</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
        <td>BMW</td>
        <td>i8</td>
        <td>Rojo</td>
        <td>Ninguna</td>
        <td>Hoose</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Mercedes Benz</td>
        <td>32432</td>
        <td>Verde</td>
        <td>Ninguna</td>
        <td>Pedro</td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Aunque no fue realmente lo que pedía en un principio, me ayudo mucho está solución y lo pude complementar junto con otras modificaciones.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes la de sacar todos los key de tu primer elemento, luego recorrerlo y guardar en otro array,

> ESTO SOLO FUNCIONARA SI EL PRIMER ELEMENTO TRAE DATOS Y ES EL ORDEN
>   QUE DESEAS

```js
var data = [
    {
      MARCA: 'A',
      NOMBRE: 'Hoose'},
    {
      MARCA: 'Z',
      NOMBRE: 'Pedro'
    },
    {
     
      NOMBRE: 'Mantequilla',
      MARCA: 'C',
    }
 ];
 
 var keys = [];
 for (k in data[0]) {
  if (data[0].hasOwnProperty(k)) {
     keys.push(k);
  }
}
let longitudArray = data.length;
let cantidadKeys = keys.length;
let finalData = [];
for(let i = 0; i< longitudArray; i++){
  let json = {} 
  for (let j = 0; j < cantidadKeys; j++) {
    k = keys[j];
    json[k] = data[i][k];
  }
  finalData.push(json);
}


console.log(finalData)
```

Comment: Necesito cambiar el orden de las llaves.

Comment: cuales son tus llaves, te refieres a llaves a tu clave primaria?

Comment: No. El orden de mi JSON en las llaves es ACC_OBSERVACIONES, MARCA, MODELO pero yo quiero cambiar el orden a MARCA, MODELO y ACC_OBSERVACIONES. No se si me explique.

Comment: acabo de edita mi respuesta.. es lo que quieres?